# Conformal coating of shielded RF modules

Tags: pcb-assembly, conformal-coating, outdoors

What is the best practice to protect a circuit with shielded RF modules?

I have a feeling that conformal coating is difficult since the shield is not sealed.

[image: rf module]

Comment: Are you trying simply to make it moisture resistant?

Comment: What's under the shield?